# How to reverse an elements in the array using Spark SQL query?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data like below
Input data
Key     data
a      [5,2,6,null,null]
b      [5,7,9,4,null,null,null]

I want output to be like below.
Output:
Key      data
a        [6,2,5,null,null]
b        [4,9,7,5,null,null,null]

Basically elements in the array needs to be reversed by keeping nulls at the end as it is.
Can someone please help me with spark SQL query?

Comment: @Lennart - Slava Ukraini nope. sort will. make the number highest to least, so basically the output in sort will be. 2,5,6,null,null. instead of 6,2,5,null,null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach - transform NULLs for sorting then transform back to NULL

```
select transform(sort_array(transform(data, x -> coalesce(x, 0)), False), x -> case when x=0 then null else x end) from table1
```

[EDIT]

Just noticed the transformations are not required if the NULLs are to be sorted at the end based on reverse order. `sort_array()` will work by itself

```
sort_array(data, False)
```

[EDIT 2]

Having it pointed out to me I misunderstood the question, I believe this will work... it's a little convoluted however:

```
select 
 concat( 
    reverse(array_except(array(5,7,9,4,null,null,null), array(null))) 
  , array_repeat(null
    , aggregate(
        transform(array(5,7,9,4,null,null,null), (x, i) -> (case when x is null then 1 else 0 end))
        , 0, (acc, x) -> acc + x
       )
     )
 )
```

The approach counts the number of nulls, removes the nulls, reverses the array and adds back the nulls at the end of the array

Comment: Would not this just sort the array? I misread the question first before I realized that the array should be reversed, not sorted

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini yes, I believe it just requires sorting in reverse order. I'm basing on the OP's example inputs & outputs

Comment: Apologies, it is a reverse rather than my solution which was a sort. My bad!

Comment: I did the same mistake, so no need to apologize :-) Since I don't know spark, I thought I just ask if it somehow worked the way the OP wants

Comment: Do you BTW happen to know where one can test snippets for SparkSQL (similar to https://dbfiddle.uk/ ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
reverse(filter(array(0, null, 2, 3, null), x -> x IS NOT NULL))
```

then append:

```
filter(array(0, null, 2, 3, null), x -> x IS NULL)
```

See [Filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter)